# Get names from bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the names of the menu that was selected to build a breadcrumb, something like on click in option Text 2, the breadcrumb will be "Text 1 | Text 2"

This is my menu:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Text 1
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu opc1">
        <li>
          <a id="1" href="#">Text 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Text 3
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu opc1">
        <li>
          <a id="1" href="#">Text 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can i get "Text 1" or "Text 3" when i click in link with "Text 2" or "Text 4"?
I can get "Text 2" or "Text 4" with:

```
$('.opc1 a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var n2_text = $(this).html();
    ...
```

I tried allready with:

```
    var n1_texto = $(this).parent('ul.nav > li.dropdown > a.dropdown-toggle').html();
    // or
    var n1_texto = $(this).parent(li.dropdown > a).html();
    //or
    var n1_texto = $(this).parent(li.dropdown).children('name of a class').html();
    ...
```

But never got the text it returns "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find text for your anchor tag.Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.opc1 a').each(function(index) {
        $(this).on("click", function(){
        var href = $(this).html();
        var paren = $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').find('a:first').html().trim(); 
        console.log(paren+"/"+href);   
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: That's to complete I did `.split(' ',1) ` instead of `trim()` to remove the `<b class="caret"></b>` that is in Text 1

Comment: m still struggling with the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/qr163spj/) to get correct answer.